# A method that reads the data from the file into the HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to write a method that reads the data from the file into the HashMap, the key of which is the number of the line of the file, and the value is the text in the line. And only the HashMap values, the keys of which are powers of 2, must be written to another file.

I created a file with a poem now. Wrote a method for reading a file that prints text in an ArrayList. It would be convenient to run a loop and get the line number and text. But I don't quite understand what to do next.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    List<String> fileToRead = FileWriterReader.ourFileReaderToList("HAMLET.txt");
    System.out.println(fileToRead);

    public static List<String> ourFileReaderToList(String fileToRead) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File(fileToRead);

        List<String> poemLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner in = null;
        try {
            if (file.exists()) {
                in = new Scanner(file);
                while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                    poemLines.add(in.nextLine());
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
        return poemLines;
    }

    public static void ourWriterListToFile(String fileToWrite, List<String> listToWrite) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileToWrite, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            int k = 0;
            for (String s : listToWrite) {
                if (k == (listToWrite.size() - 1)) {
                    bw.write(s);
                } else {
                    bw.write(s + "\n");
                }
                k++;

            }
        } finally {
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        }
    }

    public static void parsedFile(List<String> listFromFile) {
        for (String s : listFromFile)
            System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most of the task done with your existing **ourFileReaderToList()** method, you just need to modify it a little so as to accommodate a [HashMap](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm) and sum file lines as they are read in. The Return Type for your method would of course need to be **HashMap** and because you want the ***Key*** to be a file line number and the value for each key to be the actual file line string currently being read your Return Type will need to be: `HashMap<Integer, String>`:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, String> ourFileReaderToList(String fileToRead) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

Because you are no longer going to use the **List** Interface in your method you can go ahead and change that as well to your Return Type:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> poemLines = new HashMap<>();
```

Here is what your **File To HashMap** method might look like:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, String> fileToHashMap(String fileToRead) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(fileToRead));
    int lineCount = 0;
    HashMap<Integer, String> poemLines = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            lineCount++;
            String fileLine = reader.nextLine();
            // If you do not want to add blank lines to the
            // collection then uncomment the following lines;
            /*
            if (fileLine.trim().equals("")) {
                continue;
            }
            */
            poemLines.put(lineCount, fileLine); // Add to Collection
        }
    }
    finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    return poemLines;
}
```

Now that you have your collection within a HashMap you can proceed to print it based on the Powers of 2. I suppose then that this would mean data line 2 is printed first, then data line 4, then line 8, line 16, 32, 64, 128, etc, etc....until the **Powers Of** value will be greater than the available number of file lines contained within the collection (that is of course if what you mean by **powers of 2**). Here's how you might accomplish this:

```
public static void writeHashmapToFile(String fileToWrite, HashMap<Integer, String> hashmapToWrite) throws IOException {
    // Using 'Try With Resources'.
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileToWrite))) {
        int powersOf2 = 2;
        StringBuilder sb;
        for (Object objectName : hashmapToWrite.keySet()) {
            int key = (int) objectName;
            String line = hashmapToWrite.get(key);
            //System.out.println(key + "\t" + line);
            if (key == powersOf2) {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(key).append("\t").append(line).append(System.lineSeparator());
                bw.write(sb.toString());
                powersOf2 *= 2;   // Same as: powersOf2 = powersOf2 * 2
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It works perfectly. It was hard to understand for me how to get lines numbers powersOf2. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use a loop to convert the ArrayList into a HashMap. Since the ArrayList created by the `ourFileReaderToList` function stores each line separately and in order, another function could be made to read the values from the List and keep count of what the line number is.

For example:

```
HashMap listToHashMap(List<String> list) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> poemmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();    //Our hashmap
    int linenumber = 0;    //Variable to keep track of the line number

    for (String line : list) {
         poemmap.put(linenumber, line);    //Add line and line number to map
         linenumber++;                     //Increment line number
    }

    return poemmap;
}
```

This function will make a HashMap out of the List and return it. The lines can be retrieved using the HashMap `get()` function when they need to be written to the file.